# DTO and Entity in one object?

Tags: spring, validation, jpa

I am currently in a dilemma and I've been reading stuff regarding this.

I am making my DTOs be also my Entities. It looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@PasswordMatches // custom validator
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotNullOrEmpty // custom validator
    private String password;

    @Transient
    @NotNullOrEmpty // custom validator
    private String confirmPassword;
```

**Q1**: Is this acceptable or is there any better way of doing this? Because currently, before saving a `User` I am hashing the password for obvious reasons but if I `em.persist(user)` directly, it will fail because of `@PasswordMatches` is failing. It's only saving when I do `user.setConfirmPassword(hashedPassword)` just to satisfy the validation. Am I doing the right thing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While EJB3 allowed for the possibility of Entities being used as DTOs, the truth is it is still better to have separate DTOs.

Pretty soon you will find that your Entities will require annotations related to specific JPA Providers (like Hibernate) which will tie your Entities to the persistence layer. This will mean that if your Entities are passed 'up' to your presentation layer, then that layer needs to 'know' about the specific libraries/frameworks that you are using in your persistence layer. That's not much of a problem if you are doing web stuff, but if you are doing rich clients (e.g. Swing) then that can be extra baggage that your clients need to carry around.

Similarly, you will want to start annotating your Entities for the presentation layer (e.g. using `@Json` annotations). Putting these in your entities will again tie your persistence layer to your presentation layer.

Initially we fell into the trap of using our Entities to pass data up to our rich clients, but we had created over 300 Entity classes by the time we realised we needed to separate them into DTOs and persistence Entities. It was a painful experience to do that with so many Entities, but now (with over 400 Entity classes) we are glad we did it.

So, while it **is** acceptable to do what you are doing, you have already run into an issue where mixing business logic with your persistence layer has caused a problem. I would recommend you separate these out into DTOs and Entities to save you continued problems in the future.

Comment: This insight is very helpful. I am also leaning towards using DTOs now just for this. But for the record, do you have a 1-1 corresponce between DTOs and Entities? Do you manually do the mapping or are you using something for mapping DTO->Entity and vice versa?

Comment: Our DTOs are mostly 1-1, but they might have fields that only the presentation/business layers use. There are a myriad of ways to create your DTOs from your Entities. You can use Annotation Processing or a third-party utility like Dozer, but we use a custom Perl script which parses the Entity and creates (amongst other things) the corresponding DTO.

Comment: @Incognito Can you tell me what is wrong with my answer that you unaccepted it?

Comment: sorry I thought it was necessary to open a bountry. Selecting it again as best answer at least before the bountry.

Answer (score 8):

In short run, it seems productive and helps you in getting things done faster.

In the long run, **it is always better to have DTOs and Entities separate.**

As relationships between entities grow, you will realize that fetching one entity will result in child entities getting fetched as well, even though you may not need them in that specific use case.  DTOs helps you to optimize your database queries the way you need keeping the underlying entities hidden from business use cases.

Answer (score 5):

The answer also depends upon your use case. Consider these factors

1. If you anticipate, exposing your service layer to  various clients in future . In this case sharing your entity design as part of service method signature, wont be a good idea, also this may pose issues in extensible design.
2. If you are developing a small/med app, with performance as top priority on your mind, you can go with only entities from service layer(even from presentation layer) to persistence layer. Entities can have persistence specific configuration defined in an xml rather than via annotations. This is not a bad design if you have one to one mapping between DTOs and entities.Of course in this case , you will have quicker development and less bugs.
3. If you intend to keep separate beans for presentation layer (form beans) , you can also think of a mix. For example, for master entity management module- Use entities and No DTOs. For Transaction entitity management module- Use entities and DTOs.